battery issue on laptop with Ubuntu
i'm using this laptop:

ASUS N551JW
Intel® Core™ i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz × 8
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M/PCIe/SSE2
RAM 16Gb

i have multiboot GRUB on my computer with

Windows10,
Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

and when my main OS was  Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (for a long time BTW) my laptop battery died very fast - just in a few months it appeared i can work on battery for 2-3 minutes and then it shuts down with no saving my data.
i tried battery replacement - nothing helped
not so long ago i switched to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and bought a new battery for my laptop
so now i need your help to understand if issue from before is still present in my OS.
maybe some drivers/tests are needed?
i had issues before with acpi/interrupts and ath/wifi
now it seems they are solved but maybe it matters for current issue
please help my new battery not to die on Ubuntu laptop

Is it possible the new battery you bought also has issues? It can happen sometimes with "new" old stock. Like even if it's a good brand, if it sits in the warehouse for too long it degrades on it's own. tbf I can't imagine a laptop of this era would be very power efficient. But also 2-5 minutes just sounds broken. Also you dual-boot with Windows. Does the same thing happen there?

@4ngelDus7 battery is working fine from the very beginning, but when some time passes it seems like loosing capacity 'cause computer starts to work less time on full charge as if it degrades fast. i use Windows not so often only for my car programming and yes old battery dies there fast too. Now i have new battery and it works for 2 hours approx. on Ubuntu that's why i want to fix possible battery issues in advance not to kill new battery as it happened before.
